# Appcelerator titanium - drag and drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, titanium, appcelerator

I am new to Appcelerator Titanium and would like to ask, is there a way to implement drag and drop in appcelerator titanium for android? I tried the example here https://github.com/mcongrove/TiDrop
but it is not working properly on android, when i click on the box, i get the following runtime error:
Type Error: Cannot read property "y" from null (file:///android_asset/Resources/TiDrop.js#34). can anyone help me?

Thank you,

Comment: The code what you showed will work only for iPhone... for Android drag drap... i could not find any such things..

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm not able to drag and drop in android

Answer (score 0):

For android there is not globalPoint is available in event object of touch events.
Add following code to convert the touched view's point to the parent's point or global points.

```
// e is an event object of touch event

e.globalPoint = e.source.convertPointToView({
            x : e.x,
            y : e.y
        }, parentWinObj);
```

Comment: @ Sagar B., Can u post the full code changes for TiDrop.js or tabgroup.js No idea where to change this code, e.globalPoint = e.source.convertPointToView({ x : e.x, y : e.y }, parentWinObj); Please explain..  For android

Comment: Also how to drag ti.ui.tableviewrow to ti.ui.view. This is to choose some product from tableview then finally dragged items in ui.view that need be stored in sqlite. Android Titanium